# Set key for cart item when adding to cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

How to add items to cart with unique cart key . i dont want to update the quantity of cart items cart already have

eg. if we have 2 items in cart ,
then i want to add two more items to cart , instead of an item with quantity 4 , i need two cart items with quantity 2

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

You need this custom hooked function that will add to cart items a generated unique key:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'set_custom_cart_item_key', 10, 4 );
function set_custom_cart_item_key( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', $cart_item_data['unique_key'] );

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

It will avoid increasing item quantity when same product is added to cart… so you will have separated cart items instead…

Answer (score 0):

So take a look at this method in `add_to_cart()` in `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php`

```
// Load cart item data - may be added by other plugins.
$cart_item_data = (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity );

// Generate a ID based on product ID, variation ID, variation data, and other cart item data.
$cart_id        = $this->generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
```

You see the `$cart_id` takes in `$cart_item_data` which you can modify to be different from the previous items in order to generate unique id's.